# How to send response to model after authenticate using passport and backbone.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, passport.js

To authenticate, I have sent post request to server from backbone.js like this:

```
model.save({"email":"sil@gmail.com","password":"silvester"}, {
   successs:function(model,res){

   },
   error:function(){

   }
});
```

I have received in server side like this:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/mainpage',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```

in above coding if authentication success I redirect to mainpage and then I have tried to show another one html page like this:

```
app.get('/mainpage',function(req,res) {
    console.log("mainpage");
    res.sendfile('/mainpage.html');
});
```

after redirect that mainpage I got that console result but I could not redirect to another webpage. how to work it out and then is there anyway to send response only for that post request(above mentioned post request).if I send response to that post request I can easily receive that response within success function and then I can proceed my work but in passport there is only redirect option so it is going to another get request ,from this how can I sent response to frontend ? and where can I receive ?.so how to send response without redirect and how to solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

`model.save` will make an ajax request to your server.

I think when you do `res.sendfile('/mainpage.html');`, it returns the html page in ajax response. Can you check in Developer Console in the browser?

you should check that if the request is ajax then return a `401` http status code and do the redirection on the client side using `window.location="/mainpage.html"`

Answer (score 0):

it may help you to respond to same post request

> app.post('/login',   passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect:
>   '/login' }),   function(req, res) {
>       res.redirect('/mainpage');   });